# How can I disable screen update which updating a lot of controls?

Tags: delphi

I have a form with 50 or more controls which I create and add at runtime. I don't want to see then appear one by one; I would rather disable drawing/start buffering at the start & then see them all appear at once.

I seem to recall doing something like this in BCB about 10 years ago, but forget how.

Comment: You could place all these controls on a TPanel and show/hide it. But are you sure that you really need 50 controls? Maybe you would be better of with a single custom control consisting of 50 parts? I have no idea what your situation is, but in my experience, when someone adds a huge number of similar controls to a form, he/she should really build herself a new control with a huge number of similar parts!

Comment: Good point (+1), but it's not always the same controls. They are created dynamically by certain user choices, then he gets to position them. There's a Save option and it's the redraw on Load that concerns me.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

I'm not sure if there's a Delphi-specific method to do this, but using the Win32 API, this is done through the [`WM_SETREDRAW`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145219%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) message.

**Edit:** Thanks to Ken White and Sertac Akyuz for the sample code below.

```
begin
  // Defer updates
  SendMessage(Handle, WM_SETREDRAW, WPARAM(False), 0);
  try
    // Create all your controls here
  finally
    // Make sure updates are re-enabled
    SendMessage(Handle, WM_SETREDRAW, WPARAM(True), 0);
    // Invalidate;  // Might be required to reflect the changes  
  end;
end;
```

Comment: +1, I hope your answer gets a lot of upvotes quickly enough to prevent answers with [`LockWindowUpdate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145034%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Comment: LockWindowUpdate was designed to stop drawing for drag and drop, it goes a bit further than WM_SETREDRAW because it could make assumptions about what the user was doing.  One assumption was that since a drag and drop was occurring, window moving could be disabled/ignored.  You can still drag a window around that has WM_SETREDRAW set to false.

Comment: @Mawg: See "With what operations is LockWindowUpdate not meant to be used?" (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2007/02/22/1742084.aspx)

Comment: Ok, so if I don't use LockWindowUpdate, can anyone post a short code snippet using WM_SETREDRAW ?

Comment: @Mawg: I could, but I'd feel very bad stealing reputation that rightfully belongs to casablanca, so I'll let him do that! @casablanca: Please include a code snippet!

Comment: @Ken and Sertac: Thanks, both of you. I haven't used Delphi in about 10 years, so I'm glad someone was able to provide sample code.

Comment: @Sertac: No revert or re-edit required. I haven't run into a need for Invalidate the few times I've used WM_SETREDRAW, but it might be needed sometimes. I see no problem with the suggestion. :-) Thanks.

Comment: Thanks!  (although it's handle and not hwnd in that second call)

Comment: @Mawg: Good catch. I pulled the code snippet from a code sample DB I've collected, and it was C code. My quick rewrite into Delphi missed the second HWND. Thanks for pointing it out; I've fixed it for anyone who finds this in the future.

Comment: @kish: It's declared in `messages.pas`, IIRC.

Comment: Whose handle is that ? A form or it can be of any control ?

Comment: @MarusNebunu: Any control handle will work, it'll affect that control and all its children.

Answer (score 11):

I simply keep Visible = False until everything's nice and ready.

Comment: +1 That's also a possibility (I had thought of it, just wanted to see if there wasn't another way)

Comment: @Mawg, for runtime component creation it seems like keeping Visible = False "feels" better, while using WM_SETREDRAW "feels" better for updating an already existing and already visible control.

Comment: Keeping Visible=False is not that good. WM_SETREDRAW is much better. Especially, when the control is Align=alClient and connected to a TSplitter, setting Visible=False will screw up the whole layout. And it is slower too.

Comment: What if you want to lock only a panel? You cannot hide it every time, then bring it back. The flicker will be even worst.