# How to avoid display "flicker" when creating and assigning TFrames to a parent control

Tags: delphi, flicker, tframe

For example: I have a TFrame (called TPageFrame) that has a number of controls, e.g. TreeView aligned Left, splitter, and main clientarea consisting of an edit and RichEdit, as in image below:

[image]

Code looks something like this:

```
type
  TPageFrame = class(TFrame)
    Panel1: TPanel;
    Splitter1: TSplitter;
    Panel2: TPanel;
    Panel3: TPanel;
    Panel4: TPanel;
    Edit1: TEdit;
    RichEdit1: TRichEdit;
    TreeView1: TTreeView;
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
  end;
```

In the Main Form I have a a RzTabControl with a few tabs. As I move to a new tab, a new Frame will be created (stored in a Frame array) and it's parent is set to the RzTabControl.

```
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    RzTabControl1: TRzTabControl;
    procedure RzTabControl1Change(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
    FFrameArr: array[0..5] of TPageFrame;
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

procedure TForm1.RzTabControl1Change(Sender: TObject);
var
  Index: Integer;
  PageFrame: TPageFrame;
begin
  Index := RzTabControl1.TabIndex;
  Self.Caption := Index.ToString;

  if FFrameArr[Index] = nil then
  begin
    PageFrame := TPageFrame.Create(Self);
    PageFrame.Name := 'PageFrame' + Index.ToString;
    PageFrame.Parent := RzTabControl1;
    PageFrame.Align := alClient;
    PageFrame.Visible := True;
    FFrameArr[Index] := PageFrame;
  end;
end;
```

Problem: While the Frame is being created and having it's parent set, there is a lot of "Display noise":

[image]

See how edit control is painted twice in 2 positions. (Would be easier to demonstrate with a video...)

How can this kind of flicker be avoided?

Comment: Take a look at this question (and the accepted answer): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3792217/how-can-i-disable-screen-update-which-updating-a-lot-of-controls
Don't know if it'll work for you, but try it out and let us know...

Comment: Can you check the Visible property of the frame in the Object Inspector? Make sure it is False.

Comment: @Uwe: That did not make a difference

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few problems with the code by @RaelB, such as incorrect use of try/finally, not handling any exceptions that might arise to locally created variables, etc.

The correct (IMO) code should be:

```
if not Assigned(FFrameArr[Index]) then begin
  Screen.Cursor := crHourGlass;
  try
    // Defer updates
    SendMessage(Handle, WM_SETREDRAW, WPARAM(False), 0);
    try
      PageFrame := TPageFrame.Create(Self);
      try
        PageFrame.Name := 'PageFrame' + Index.ToString;
        PageFrame.Visible := False;
        PageFrame.Parent := RzTabControl1;
        PageFrame.Align := alClient;
        PageFrame.Visible := True;
        FFrameArr[Index] := PageFrame;
      except
        PageFrame.Free;
        raise
      end;
    finally
      // Make sure updates are re-enabled
      SendMessage(Handle, WM_SETREDRAW, WPARAM(True), 0);
    end;
    PageFrame.Hide;
    PageFrame.Show;
    RzTabControl1.Invalidate;
  finally
    Screen.Cursor := crDefault;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the correct usage of try..finally, however your code does not work. `PageFrame.Hide to RzTabControl1.Invalidate` must come after the second call to SendMessage

Comment: @RaelB: Really (not that I doubt you)?. I wouldn't have expected that. But I have updated the code to reflect that...

Comment: Yes, The second call to SendMessage leaves the surface blank. Hide/Show is required to refresh.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks to @HeartWare, based on [How can I disable screen update which updating a lot of controls?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3792217/how-can-i-disable-screen-update-which-updating-a-lot-of-controls)

This works remarkably well:

```
  if FFrameArr[Index] = nil then
  begin
    Screen.Cursor := crHourGlass;
    // Defer updates
    SendMessage(Handle, WM_SETREDRAW, WPARAM(False), 0);
    try
      PageFrame := TPageFrame.Create(Self);
      PageFrame.Name := 'PageFrame' + Index.ToString;
      PageFrame.Visible := False;
      PageFrame.Parent := RzTabControl1;
      PageFrame.Align := alClient;
      PageFrame.Visible := True;
      FFrameArr[Index] := PageFrame;
    finally
      // Make sure updates are re-enabled
      SendMessage(Handle, WM_SETREDRAW, WPARAM(True), 0);
      PageFrame.Hide;
      PageFrame.Show;
      RzTabControl1.Invalidate;
      Screen.Cursor := crDefault;
    end;
  end;
```

Comment: The use of finally is wrong here. The SendMessage is the only thing that should appear there. Remember that a finally block is used to ensure code executes in the face of an exception.

Comment: Especially problematic is the TPageFrame.Create appearing _inside_ the TRY block. If an exception happens within that call, the FINALLY part will be executed, but PageFrame variable will _not_ have been initialized, thus making an Access Violation at PageFrame.Hide. This is common error in TRY/FINALLY code.